# Mysql segregating data from one column to many based on another column

Tags: mysql

How to populate selective values from one column to another column based on condition on second column? I have data in the following format

```
**name         role_id** 
-------------------------
jack           6 
jill           8  
humpty         9 
dumpty         9
```

Looking for Output

```
**'6'          '8'       '9'** 
-------------------------------
jack        jill      humpty
NULL        NULL      dumpty
```

so how can I segregate data based on role_id?

Comment: Are there only three `role_id` values in your table?

Comment: if there are more than three `role_id` values, better use some server side script to create such output.

Comment: This is called pivot table or cross tabulated (crosstab) query. The linked topic contains mysql implementation for both static (columns are known in advance) and dynamic (columns are determined on the fly) pivot.